# How to open a webpage stored in a string/bytes without creating a temp file?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Let say I some HTML code saved in either a string or bytes

```
html = "<head>" \
       "<title>My Website</title>" \
       "</head>"
```

Without saving that HTML into a .html using a library like `tempfile`, is there a way to tell Selenium to take that stored HTML, and open it on a browser? I assume it will be something along the lines of...

`driver.get(f'something{html.something_else}')`

I have looked into using `StringIO` or `BytesIO` but it eventually led me to having again to creating a temp file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put your HTML to browser with Selenium you need to use the following syntax:

```
html = "<head>" \
       "<title>My Website</title>" \
       "</head>"

driver.get("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + html_content)
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit more information for those who's situation is a bit more complicated (like mine was). If the code contains special characters, run the html code through `urllib`'s `quote` function.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html

```
from urllib.parse import quote

html = "<head>" \
       "<title>My Website</title>" \
       "</head>"

driver.get(f'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,{quote(html)}')
```

---

If you initially got the HTML code from a MIME and it's in quoted-printable format, use `quopri`'s `decodestring` function.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/quopri.html

```
from quopri import decodestring
from urllib.parse import quote

html = "<head>" \
       "<title>My Website</title>" \
       "</head>"

html_decoded = decodestring(str.encode(html))
driver.get(f'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,{quote(html_decoded)}')
```